# Need script to change div background via input.. Not working

Tags: html, input, background-color

I would like to change the background color of the DIV that contains my input field.  I got the code working correctly when you type data in the input the background color changes red.  But when I go back and erase the data leaving the input field blank, the background does not go back to it's original color.

I need the background color of the DIV to revert back to its original color when blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#id").keypress(function() {
if($("#id").val().length > 0) $("#in").css("background-color", "red");
 else {
   if($("#id").val().length = 0) $("#in").css("background-color", "grey"); 
 }

 });
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug:

```
else {
if($("#id").val().length = 0)
```

Should be:

```
else {
if($("#id").val().length == 0)
```

Also, never leave out the braces around if statements in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#id").keypress(function() {
if($("#id").val().length > 0) $("#in").css("background-color", "red");
 else {
  if($("#id").val().length == 0) $("#in").css("background-color", "grey");
 }

 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

beside the already mentioned bug, try this.
put these two classes in your css file:

```
.greyColor
{
background-color: grey;
}

.redColor
{
background-color: red;
}
```

And use in your javascript the addClass and removeClass functions:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#id").keypress(function() {
if($("#id").val().length > 0)
{
    $("#in").addClass("redColor");
}
else {
   if($("#id").val().length == 0) 
{
$("#in").addClass("greyColor");
$("#in").removeClass("redColor");
}
}

});
});
</script>
```